# Determine if a set is a subspace of another one. What does the word fixed mean here?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am solving the following problem:

> For k ∈ R (real number) and A ∈ R^(n x n) fixed, V = R^n and W = {x ∈ R^n | Ax = kx}

Now I apply the rule which is if you have a c ∈ R and u ∈ V then c*u ∈ V
I take c = -4 and x = (3,3) => c*u = (-12, -12) then to see if c*u is ∈ V we have:

*If i take n=2, then I take u*x = (3,3), A = [2,2 --- 2,2], k = -5 and then I do the A (c*u) = k (c*u) and I get as a result (-48, -48) = (60, 60) which is not true.

Now my QUESTION is that what does that word "FIXED" mean in the sentence of the problem, does that change anything?

Comment: It just means they are no variables in the sense that you have to find their values. They are "given" to you. It's like when I say "I have $x$ apples and give away $y$ apples, how many apples do I have?". The answer is $x-y$. The values $x$ and $y$ are fixed in the sense that they are part of the question. I don't say you what are the values of $x$ or $y$, but you still can solve the question without that knowledge.

Comment: "Fixed" just means that the number represented by the letter $k$ and the matrix represented by the letter $A$ doesn't change. They could be any number and matrix, but when trying to figure out what $W$ is, they do not change. They are, in principle, known / given to you, although the problem authors want you to solve the problem so that it works no matter what they actually are.

Comment: Okay thank you and W here is not a subspace of V, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing up which order we take different vectors and numbers here.

Consider $W\subseteq V$ as a subset. We want to prove that it is a subspace. For it to be a subspace, we need three things:

1. $\vec 0\in W$. Clearly $A\vec 0 = k\vec 0$, so $\vec 0$ fulfills the requirement for being an element of $W$.
2. For any $\vec u, \vec v \in W$, we have $\vec u + \vec v\in W$. This we just check:$$A(\vec u + \vec v) = A\vec u + A\vec v = k\vec u+k\vec v = k(\vec u + \vec v)$$so $\vec u + \vec v$ fulfills the requirement of being in $W$ as long as $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ both do.
3. For any $c\in \Bbb R$ and $\vec v\in W$ we have $c\vec v\in W$. Again, we just check:
   $$
   A(c\vec v) = c(A\vec v) = c(k\vec v) = k(c\vec v)
   $$so $c\vec v$ fulfills the defining requirement of $W$ as long as $\vec v\in W$.

With all three properties checked, this means that $W$ is indeed a subspace of $V$. It is known as "the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $k$".